# Multiple tethering icon stuck in Notification bar of CM12 (for OnePlus One)

Tags: cyanogenmod, tethering, notification-icons, oneplus-one

- Device: OnePlus One
- Android: CM12 (0YL).
- Status: Rooted, Xposed Framework installed.

---

Whenever I activate both USB tethering and Wifi hotspot, the icon [image] appears in Notification bar to signify that multiple tethering connections are activated. The problem is whenever I disable wifi hotspot and USB tethering their corresponding icons disappear as usual but this icon [image: ​] remains stuck in the bar. The icon disappears after reboot but that's not how I want to get rid of this icon.

I tried enabling (again) both USB tethering and wifi hotspot and disabling them altogether but the icon always persist.

**What should I do to get rid of this icon other than to reboot?**

**Edit**: What's the reason behind this issue?

---

<sup>I want to avoid Factory-reset or flashing the ROM.</sup>

Comment: [Brandon](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/118227/brandon) couldn't comment but wanted to say: "*I have my icons get stuck or not show up a lot on the notification bar. Most of the time when I reboot to recovery and wipe the system cache it fixes it. Try that*"

Comment: I also have this problem on CM12.1, the tethering icon doesn't go away after turning off tethering . I normally just solve it by simply rebooting the phone. After wiping the phone I still had this problem.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab It must be a bug then if it exists in CM12.1 as well. Did you encounter any related bug report?

Comment: no, only the icon

Comment: I can't test this for you, becuase unfortunately I don't have CM12 anymore (see my latest question), but you maybe can use Tasker and add something like,`when tethering switched off -> force stop tethering/remove notification`.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab As far as my findings are concerned, tethering is not a specific app but a part of Settings activity (`.SubSettings`), but force-stopping Settings doesn't help. Checking the notifications, I see that tethering notification is under the direct control of Android system (`pkg=android`) so force-stopping is not an option for it using Tasker.

Comment: I tested with the build cm-12.1-20151117-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1K6 and the problem doesn't persist there.

Answer (score 0):

I have my icons get stuck or not show up a lot on the notification bar. Most of the time when I reboot to recovery and wipe the system cache it fixes it. Try that.

Comment: I possibly won't try this because I don't know why  your solution (or how exactly it) would fix the issue. But thank you for answering, and I've added the body as a comment on the question if this answer gets deleted for some reason. // On a side note, could you mention for how long after fixing the cache you didn't face this issue again?